# Send XMLHttpRequest containing script-tags

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, xmlhttprequest, base64

So, I've built my own rudimentary CMS, that contains a backend page where admins can input stuff like page title, description, social media profiles, and so on. I have also made inputs for code injections in head and body – meant for tracking. I'm saving the form data by making it into a string and posting it with a XMLHttpRequest to a PHP file. To make the data into a string I use base64 encoding. However – while text, urls, and simple html markup works fine, this does not play well with quotation marks or script tags. They either produce malformed characters after they are inserted, or they seem to prevent the string from being inserted at all. Does anybody have an idea about how to achieve this?

Here is the relevant part of my javascript:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
siteInfo.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let trackingHead = btoa(codeEditorHead.getValue());
  let trackingBody = btoa(codeEditorBody.getValue());
  let requestString = 'tracking-head=' + trackingHead + '&tracking-body=' + trackingBody;
  request.open('POST', '/includes/update-siteinfo.php', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  request.send(requestString);
});
```

Oh, and btw, I use CodeMirror for the input field, hence the getValue function.

Here is the corresponding PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST['tracking-head'])) {
    $trackingHead = base64_decode($_POST['tracking-head']);
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['tracking-body'])) {
    $trackingBody = base64_decode($_POST['tracking-body']);
  }
}
```

After this is some error handling and the insert statement. Obviously none of my error handlers fires, which leads me to beliveve the issue is in the javascript request and not in the php.

Is this an encoding issue? Am I using the wrong headers? Is base64 the best way to stringify code? Or have I perhaps misunderstood something fundamental about how XMLHttpRequests works? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. MySQL aparrently does not let you store executable scripts in the database, to prevent SQL-injections I guess. The right way to to this is to store the data encoded, and then decode it where you want it to be outputted.

This is how I altered my Javascript:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
siteInfo.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let trackingHead = encodeURIComponent(codeEditorHead.getValue());
  let trackingBody = encodeURIComponent(codeEditorBody.getValue());
  let requestString = 'tracking-head=' + trackingHead + '&tracking-body=' + trackingBody;
  request.open('POST', '/includes/update-siteinfo.php', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  request.send(requestString);
});
```

Notice I use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `btoa()`, to escape special characters. I guess you could use either, but to me it makes more sense to wait until the next step with base64 encoding – so that both encoding and decoding is done in PHP.

Here is the PHP file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST['tracking-head'])) {
    $trackingHead = base64_encode($_POST['tracking-head']);
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['tracking-body'])) {
    $trackingBody = base64_encode($_POST['tracking-body']);
  }
}
```

Then you can use `base64_decode()` when you echo the row from the database, and you're all set. There – hope someone else out there finds this useful. :)